# Replace value in dictionary by looping through list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a dictionary

```yaml
animals: {
  dogs: [
    "spot",
    "rex"
  ],
  cats: [
    "mittens",
    "felix"
  ]
}
```

and a list of dictionaries

```yaml
"details": [
    {
        "pet_id": "5ac76261-7792-46a6-93d9-a8e85da9a51b",
        "pet_name": "spot",
        "owner": "mr. smith"
    },
    {
        "pet_id": "753b1bc9-7309-4e34-8cfd-e68984a25254",
        "pet_name": "mittens",
        "owner": "billy"
    },
    {
        "pet_idwner": "883ee5d7-93c1-4c60-89dc-69001f98173f",
        "pet_name": "rex",
        "owner": "ms. harrison"
    },
    {
        "pet_id": "b1c55e7f-4cc6-4605-b853-7f2e068b87b7",
        "pet_name": "felix",
        "owner": "frank"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to replace the name in `animals` with an identifier from `details`

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    replace_name_with_id: |
      {% for k, v in animals.items() %}
      {{k}}: 
      {% for item in v %}
      {% if item in details.pet_name %}
        - {{details[item].pet_id}}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

What I would like to end up with is

```yaml
animals: {
  dogs: [
    "5ac76261-7792-46a6-93d9-a8e85da9a51b",
    "883ee5d7-93c1-4c60-89dc-69001f98173f"
  ],
  cats: [
    "753b1bc9-7309-4e34-8cfd-e68984a25254",
    "b1c55e7f-4cc6-4605-b853-7f2e068b87b7"
  ]
}
```

But what I am getting is

> ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  name_id: "{{ details|items2dict(key_name='pet_name', value_name='pet_id') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  name_id:
    felix: b1c55e7f-4cc6-4605-b853-7f2e068b87b7
    mittens: 753b1bc9-7309-4e34-8cfd-e68984a25254
    rex: 883ee5d7-93c1-4c60-89dc-69001f98173f
    spot: 5ac76261-7792-46a6-93d9-a8e85da9a51b
```

Use it in the template

```yaml
  animals_id_str: |
    {% for k,v in animals.items() %}
    {{ k }}: {{ v|map('extract', name_id) }}
    {% endfor %}
  animals_id: "{{ animals_id_str|from_yaml }}"
```

give what you want

```yaml
  animals_id:
    cats:
    - 753b1bc9-7309-4e34-8cfd-e68984a25254
    - b1c55e7f-4cc6-4605-b853-7f2e068b87b7
    dogs:
    - 5ac76261-7792-46a6-93d9-a8e85da9a51b
    - 883ee5d7-93c1-4c60-89dc-69001f98173f
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    animals:
      cats: [mittens, felix]
      dogs: [spot, rex]

    details:
    - owner: mr. smith
      pet_id: 5ac76261-7792-46a6-93d9-a8e85da9a51b
      pet_name: spot
    - owner: billy
      pet_id: 753b1bc9-7309-4e34-8cfd-e68984a25254
      pet_name: mittens
    - owner: ms. harrison
      pet_id: 883ee5d7-93c1-4c60-89dc-69001f98173f
      pet_name: rex
    - owner: frank
      pet_id: b1c55e7f-4cc6-4605-b853-7f2e068b87b7
      pet_name: felix

    name_id: "{{ details|items2dict(key_name='pet_name', value_name='pet_id') }}"

    animals_id_str: |
      {% for k,v in animals.items() %}
      {{ k }}: {{ v|map('extract', name_id) }}
      {% endfor %}
    animals_id: "{{ animals_id_str|from_yaml }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: name_id
    - debug:
        var: animals_id|to_nice_yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but asking `if item in details.pet_name` doesn't make any sense: `details` is a list, and it does not have `pet_name` attribute. If it needs to stay a list, then you'll need to iterate through it to find the matching pet name:

```
- set_fact:
    replace_name_with_id: |
      {% for animal, names in animals.items() %}
      {{ animal }}:
      {% for name in names %}
      {% for detail in details %}
      {% if name == detail.pet_name %}
      - {{ detail.pet_id }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

That's fine for small lists, but will have a big impact on performance with larger sets of data. If you can restructure `details` as a dictionary keyed by `pet_name` you'll be in better shape, because then you can use a simple membership check (`if name in details`) which has *O(1)* performance.

Incidentally, the above produces a correctly structured YAML document, but Ansible doesn't convert this automatically into a data structure, so you would need an additional step:

```
- set_fact:
    replace_name_with_id: "{{ replace_name_with_id|from_yaml }}"
```

---

Running this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - animals.json
    - details.json

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      replace_name_with_id: |
        {% for animal, names in animals.items() %}
        {{ animal }}:
        {% for name in names %}
        {% for detail in details %}
        {% if name == detail.pet_name %}
        - {{ detail.pet_id }}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

  - set_fact:
      replace_name_with_id: "{{ replace_name_with_id|from_yaml }}"

  - debug:
      var: replace_name_with_id
```

Produces this output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "replace_name_with_id": {
        "cats": [
            "753b1bc9-7309-4e34-8cfd-e68984a25254",
            "b1c55e7f-4cc6-4605-b853-7f2e068b87b7"
        ],
        "dogs": [
            "5ac76261-7792-46a6-93d9-a8e85da9a51b",
            "883ee5d7-93c1-4c60-89dc-69001f98173f"
        ]
    }
}
```

---

We can replace the loop over details with a `selectattr` expression:

```
- set_fact:
    replace_name_with_id: |
      {% for animal, names in animals.items() %}
      {{ animal }}:
      {% for name in names %}
      - {{ (details|selectattr("pet_name", "eq", name)|first).pet_id }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

We're still performing the same iteration over `details`, but it will be faster. Note that as written, this will simply blow up in the event that there's no matching `pet_name` in `details`.

Comment: Thanks larsks. All good learning points for me, especially the mistake i was creating when calling "if item in details.pet_name", thanks for pointing out the issue with this. Also, for showing the double loop within Jinja and explaining that converting to a dictionary would perform much faster. Appreciate the good advise here